# Sending using Amazon SES in VB with CDO - can't send

Tags: vb.net, smtp, amazon-ses

Sending using Amazon SES in VB with CDO - can't send:

- We have tried using port 587 with SSL - no luck
- We have tried using port 465 with SSL - no luck
- We have tried using port 587 withOUT SSL - no luck
- We have tried using port 25 - 530 Auth required (password is there and valid)

Any idea what we are doing wrong?

```
Call SendEmail 

Sub SendEmail()

  Const cdoSendUsingPort                = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).
  Const cdoReturnReceiptTo              = "urn:schemas:mailheader:return-receipt-to"
  Const cdoBasic                        = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication

  On Error Resume Next

  Dim objFSO, objTextFile
  Set objFSO      = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objTextFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("c:\temp\Emails\RS_15031605_XENCO2_20150323_163107.log", True)

  Set objMessage                        = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
  If  err.Number <> 0 Then
      objTextFile.WriteLine("[result=-1](" & err.Description & ")")
      objTextFile.Close
      Exit Sub
  End If

  objMessage.Subject                    = "test message"
  objMessage.From                       = """LIMS Administrator"" <reporting@clientdomain.com> "
  objMessage.ReplyTo                    = "Client name <reporting@clientdomain.com>"
  objMessage.Fields(cdoReturnReceiptTo) = "Client name <reporting@clientdomain.com>"
  objMessage.Fields.Update 
  objMessage.To                         = "email@domain.com"
  objMessage.CC                         = "email@domain.com"
  objMessage.TextBody                   = "Test"

  objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")             = cdoSendUsingPort
  objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")            = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
  objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate")      = cdoBasic
  objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")          = "VALIDAMAZONSESUSERNAMELOOKSLIKETHIS->ygyg66Ygyg987g8yg987g"
  objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")          = "*******VALIDAMAZONSESPASSWORDHERE**************"
  objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")        = 25
  objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl")            = False
  objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
  objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

  objMessage.Send
  If  err.Number <> 0 Then
      objTextFile.WriteLine("[result=-2](" & err.Description & ")")
      objTextFile.Close
      Exit Sub
  End If

  objTextFile.WriteLine("[result=0]()")
  objTextFile.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you converted your password in to the SMTP Password? This link is specific to Linux but you should get the idea: https://www.lisenet.com/2014/convert-iam-secret-access-key-to-ses-smtp-password-in-bash/

Comment: Are you trying to force SES to send the email using different default port?

Comment: We have not converted the password to a an SMTP password.  I thought this was usable as they provided it to us.  Is there a web form somewhere to do this?

Comment: Q:  Are you trying to force SES to send the email using different default port?   A:  We have tried port 25, 465 and 587 all with no luck.